# How to use a drawable resource as a background color?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a drawable resource and I want to use it as a background color for my lazy column items.

Code:

```
    @Composable
fun HabitItem(
    habit: Habit,
    onDeleteClick: () -> Unit,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
             .background(//I want to place the drawable resource here)
    ) {
```

Any help?

Note:
The purpose of using drawable resource instead of a color is that I want to add corner radius to the items. So if there is a way to add a corner radius without drawable that will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

For corner radius just use:

```
    Modifier.clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .background(color)
```

Do the clipping before the background.

More [here](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/foundation/shape/#roundedcornershape).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `.background` with `.paint` inside your `Row`

Something like that:

```kotlin
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(8.dp)
        .paint(
            painter = painterResource(
                id = R.drawable.ic_name
            )
         )
) {}
```